# Auto-load trace listener to all new trace sources

Tags: c#, trace, system.diagnostics, tracelistener

I am converting some code to use Microsoft tracing. What I'd like is to define all the listeners in one project and then use them from other assemblies, without having to explicitly load them there.

To clarify, this is what I'm doing now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
      <trace autoflush="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="myListener" type="ConsoleApplication4.LogListener, ConsoleApplication4"/>
          <remove name="Default" />
        </listeners>
      </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
  </configuration>
```

And in the C# code:

```
var b = Trace.Listeners;
TraceSource tr = new TraceSource("Blah", SourceLevels.All);
tr.Listeners.Add(b["myListener"]);
tr.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 5, "Hello");
```

What I would like is for `myListener` to be automatically added to any new trace source I create without having to look it up the way I'm doing now. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Define the trace source along with its listeners in config:

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="Blah" switchValue="Warning">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <!-- Note these are in sharedListeners rather than trace -->
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="myListener" ... />
  </sharedListeners>
  <!-- Autoflush still works as expected -->
  <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

Then construct the TraceSource in code the way you already are (its trace level will be overridden by the `switchValue` in config), *don't* add any listeners to it and log to it as normal.